# CreatedAtRoute for Web Api in ASP.NET MVC 6

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-core-mvc

Web API 2 has the IHttpActionResult abstraction, which allows for easier testing and the use of helper methods in ApiController actions which return various implementations of the interface.

Looking at Web Api in MVC 6, I don't see an equivalent API, which means that a POST action in a controller would need to call Url.RouteUrl and explicitly set the status code and location header on Context.Response, making it necessary to include a lot of mundane setup code in unit tests.

My question is whether there are plans to bring the Web API 2 approach into MVC 6, and if there is a recommended workaround in the meantime?

Comment: In terms of a workaround, there is the Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.WebApiCompatShim NuGet package, which lets you call services.AddWebApiConventions in Startup.ConfigureServices.  After that, you can call Ok, CreatedAtRoute, etc in an ApiController class to return an IActionResult. The package will then need to be used in the unit test project.

Comment: The best place to ask this would be to log an issue on https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues, where the MVC / Web API team is working on the product.